# How to update and show in real time on label 2 what user write in ENTRY label1?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

If i have this ENTRY label1 on pos1, how can i update and show "in real time" the text i write on other label 2 in position2?

```
label1 = Entry(root, font=('aria label', 15), fg='black')
label1.insert(0, 'enter your text here')
label1_window = my_canvas.create_window(10, 40, window=entry)

label2 = how to update and show in real time what user write on label1
```

Comment: Isn’t this the same question you already asked once before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues in your attempt**:  The variable names are not clear as you are creating an `Entry` component and then assigning it to a variable named `label1` which can be confusing.

**Hints**: You can do one of the following to tie the label to the entry so that changing the text in the entry causes the text in the label to change:

1. Use a shared variable
2. Implement a suitable callback function.  You can, for example, update the label each time the `KeyRelease` event occurs.

**Solution 1 - Shared variable**: Below is a sample solution using a shared variable:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Example')
root.geometry("300x200+10+10")

user_var = StringVar(value='Enter text here')

user_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=user_var, font=('aria label', 15), fg='black')
user_entry.pack()

echo_label = Label(root, textvariable=user_var)
echo_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Solution 2 - Callback function**: Below is a sample solution using a suitable callback function. This is useful if you wish to do something more:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Example')
root.geometry("300x200+10+10")


def user_entry_changed(e):
    echo_label.config({'text': user_entry.get()})


user_entry = Entry(root, font=('aria label', 15), fg='black')
user_entry.insert(0, 'Enter your text here')
user_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", user_entry_changed)
user_entry.pack()

echo_label = Label(root, text='<Will echo here>')
echo_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Output**: Here is the resulting output after entering `'abc'` in the entry field:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the entry and label use the same `StringVar` For the `textvariable` option, the label will automatically show whatever is in the entry. This will happen no matter whether the entry is typed in, or you programmatically modify the entry.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=200, background="bisque")
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)

canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

canvas.create_window(10, 40, window=entry, anchor="w")

root.mainloop()
```

[image]